# RN - ProgressBarAndroid: manually calling React.PropTypes for the `indeterminate` prop

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I added `ProgressBarAndroid` after getting `ProgressViewIOS` working in my app. However I'm getting a strange error that I can't get rid of. As the error says and you'll notice in my code below - I'm not using React.Proptypes. I see the progress bar working in the android emulator. My only thought is maybe [I'm the third party case](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html#fixing-the-false-positive-in-third-party-proptypes), as linked in the warning message, but I don't see how.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ProgressViewIOS, ProgressBarAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from '~/utils/styles'

export default class ProgressBar extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
      start: props.start || 0,
      distance: props.distance,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.updateProgress()
    }, 100)
  }

    updateProgress = () => {
    var start = this.state.start + 0.01;
    this.setState({ start });
    if(start < this.state.distance){
      requestAnimationFrame(() => this.updateProgress());
    }    
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearTimeout(this.updateProgress)
  }

  render () {
      if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
        return (
            <ProgressViewIOS
              progress={this.state.start}
              style={{height: 3}}
              progressViewStyle={'bar'}
              progressTintColor={this.props.progressTintColor}
            />
          )
      }

      if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
        return (
            <ProgressBarAndroid 
                indeterminate={false} 
                styleAttr="Horizontal"
                color={this.props.progressTintColor || colors.defaultBlue}
                progress={this.state.start}
                style={{height: 5}} 
            />
        )
      }
        return null
  } 
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning originates from `indeterminate` prop of the `ProgressBarAndroid`.

Looking into the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ProgressBarAndroid/ProgressBarAndroid.android.js), it is complaining on the `indeterminate` custom propType which it did not pass in the "[secret](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html#fixing-the-false-positive-in-third-party-proptypes)" last argument that is then passed to `ReactPropTypes.bool` function.

While waiting for a PR in React Native, you could fix it by:

1. Open the following file:

   > PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ProgressBarAndroid/ProgressBarAndroid.android.js
2. Look for the function `var indeterminateType = function(props, propName, componentName)`.
3. Add the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...rest`) so the "secret" last argument will be passed along:

`var indeterminateType = function(props, propName, componentName, ...rest) {`

and

`return ReactPropTypes.bool(props, propName, componentName, ...rest) || checker();`